# textarea shows 2 lines when htmlText is set

Tags: actionscript-3, textarea, flash-10

I am using a TextArea. I set its htmlText as follows:

```
textArea.htmlText = '<P ALIGN="CENTER"><FONT FACE="_sans" SIZE="14" COLOR="#FFFF00" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0"></FONT></P>';
```

The problem is that there are always 2 lines in text area when it runs. When I remove this i get usual one line but then i m not able to set color and all.

I want to use textarea, set different colors on it and I don't want 2 lines in that.

Comment: Could you explain your problem a bit more?

Comment: also, have you tried "textArea.multiline = false;" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi probably this is the flash bug. i think `<p></p>` tag creates new line itself so i just removed `<p></p>` tags from htmlText and it solved my problem

Actually if i remove `<p></p>` then there is a format problem so the best solution is to remove '>' from `<p>something</p>` so new line will not be there.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Also the condenseWhite option...

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#condenseWhite

Comment: thanks for replying i tried that but it didn't solved my problem. But still nice info i didn't know about that. Regards